# Abstract Dao not updating or saving with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I'm having and issue with Hibernate where I'm trying to save and entity through and Abstract Dao class and it seems to not want to save or update however my delete functionality seems to work flawlessly. So I was wondering if someone could point out where I seem to be going wrong.

I did debug to see that the entity is in-fact fully loaded into the variable when it goes to update or save.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

The class where I'm pulling all the data in:

```
        try{
        accountDao.add(newAccount);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        this.addActionError("And unknown error has occurred please try refreshing the page");
        return INPUT;
    }
```

Which goes to this hibernate utility class, the entity data is in the parameter being passed into the add function being called but it just seems that hibernate won't save it:

```
    public abstract class AbstractDao<Entity> extends HibernateDaoSupport {

    public void add(Entity entity) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(entity);
    }

    public void delete(Entity entity) {
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(entity);
    }

    public abstract List<Entity> findAll();

    public abstract List<Entity> findById(Long id);

    public void update(Entity entity) {
        getHibernateTemplate().update(entity);
    }

}
```

Bean definition

```
<bean id="accountDao" class="com.dao.AccountDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="utilityDao" class="com.dao.UtilityDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="account_usageDao" class="com.dao.Account_UsageDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

    <bean id="addCustomerInfo" class="com.action.customer.AddAction" scope="prototype">
    <property name="accountDao" ref="accountDao"/>
    <property name="utilityDao" ref="utilityDao"/>
    <property name="account_usageDao" ref="account_usageDao"/>
</bean>
```

Update 1: Bean definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell without seeing more of the implementation.  It appears you are using spring.  This problem usually happens to me when I forget to define a transaction context.

Have a look at: [Spring Transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am using Spring, Hibernate, Struts2 and I read through most of that and I believe I'm giving hibernate a proper context with my bean definition, but I will explore that area some more.

Comment: Pointed me in the right direction, and I further debugged it to find out Hibernate was being upset by Dates being casted to strings according to my catch statement, which I really should've caught before I posted here. Thanks again though!